# почему слушатель на resize срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: reactjs

перерендера нету... в обычном js срабатывает один раз... а в react почему то два раза не пойму никак почему

```
export const App = () => {
  const resizeMax = () => {
      if(window.innerWidth < 450){
        console.log(`max`);
        window.removeEventListener('resize',resizeMax)
        window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMin)
      }
    }
    
    const resizeMin = () => {
      if(window.innerWidth >= 450){
        console.log(`min`);
        window.removeEventListener('resize',resizeMin)
        window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMax)
      }
    }
    if(window.innerWidth < 450){
      window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMin)
    }else{
        window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMax)
    }
  return <></>
}
```

вот так работает как задумано НО почему

```
useEffect(() => {
if(window.innerWidth < 450){
          window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMin)
        }else{
            window.addEventListener('resize',resizeMax)
        }
},[])
```